# twitterImgBot stops working after some hours

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to get this, https://github.com/joaquinlpereyra/twitterImgBot, to work 
and it works and it seems ok. 
But after some hours, it stops working and this error comes up:

```
*python3 twitterbot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 118, in build_path
    value = quote(self.session.params[name])
KeyError: 'id'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitterbot.py", line 209, in <module>
    main()
  File "twitterbot.py", line 200, in main
    orders()
  File "twitterbot.py", line 118, in orders
    timeline.delete_tweet_by_id(tweet.in_reply_to_status_id, api)
  File "/home/user/Skrivebord/twitterboot/lo/bot/timeline.py", line 12, in delete_tweet_by_id
    api.destroy_status(id_to_delete)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 245, in _call
    method = APIMethod(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.build_path()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 120, in build_path
    raise TweepError('No parameter value found for path variable: %s' % name)
tweepy.error.TweepError: No parameter value found for path variable: id*
```

It seems like the Python has some problem because if I make a new install on a another PC it works for some hours and then stops. 
Strange.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because `tweet` is not in reply to a status, so has an `in_reply_to_status_id` attribute that's `None`, so `API.destroy_status` is called with an `id` of `None`.